# Make clothes too many vertices?

Tags: export

I'm trying to make some custom clothes using the MakeClothes plugin, and everything is going well until I try to export the mesh.  I'll usually get an error message indicating it's got both tris and quads.  Using the remesh modifier usually results in a loss of detail, and creates millions of vertices.  As such, I'll apply a triangulate modifier.

After this, the MakeClothes plugin will make the clothes and export without throwing up any errors.  However, when I then go to use these clothes in MakeHuman, I get an error message saying:
"Failed to index faces of mesh human.001.obj, you are probably loading a mesh with mixed nb of verts per face (do not mix tris and quads). Or your mesh has too many faces attached to one vertex (the maximum is 8-poles). In the second case, either increase MAX_FACES for this mesh, or improve the mesh topology. Original error message: () could not broadcast input array from shape (9) into shape (8)".

I've previously had this error from the MakeClothes exporter as well, and so I know it should pick up both of these cases.  It isn't picking this up, yet MakeHuman is failing on it.  Can anyone please clarify what's going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: Sounds like its a bug in the exporter (or possibly make human). If the exporter is not picking up on it. You could try looking in the system console (*Window* > *Toggle System Console*) to see if the addon is producing any weird output. Otherwise, maybe contact the addon devs. Also, apply any modifiers before export, that can make a difference.

Comment: I've found what it is.  Turns out that while the MakeClothes exporter allows all tris or all quads, Makehuman only works with all quads.

Comment: Ah interesting. Could you add that as an answer to the question when possible, for future people who might see this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found what it is. Turns out that while the MakeClothes exporter allows all tris or all quads, Makehuman only works with all quads.  As such, all meshes need to be quads for MakeHuman to work properly.